# Set Barcode to Code39?

Tags: pdfclown

Looking at sample barcode script.  I wonder how do I set the barcode to code39 for it to work for vehicle's VIN?

```
                pdfclownEntities::EAN13Barcode barcode = new pdfclownEntities::EAN13Barcode(parmBookValues.Vin);
                XObject barcodeXObject = barcode.ToXObject(parmDocument);
                primitiveComposer.ShowXObject(
                    barcodeXObject,
                    new dotnetDrawing::PointF(boxAdjustedPositionX, boxAdjustedPositionY),
                    GeomUtils.Scale(barcodeXObject.Size, new dotnetDrawing::SizeF(boxWidthX, boxHeightY)),
                    XAlignmentEnum.Right,
                    YAlignmentEnum.Bottom,
                    0
                );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code39 is not implemented at the moment, sorry